# How to convert json array into Postgres int array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a scenario where I need to convert a json array into a Postgres int array and query it for the result. Below is my array

```
      ID            DATA
       1           {"bookIds" : [1,2,3,5], "storeIds": [2,3]} 
       2           {"bookIds" : [4,5,6,7], "storeIds": [1,3]}
       3           {"bookIds" : [11,12,10,9], "storeIds": [4,3]}
```

I want to convert `booksId` array into int array and later query it. Is it possible in Postgres 9.3? I know 9.4 + provides much more JSON support but I can't update my db at the moment.

The below query gives me the error

```
  Select data::json->>'bookIds' :: int[] from table

 ERROR:  malformed array literal: "bookIds"
 LINE 1: Select data::json->>'bookIds' :: int[] from table
```

Is it possible to query elements inside json array in Postgres 9.3?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The setup in the question should look like this:

```
create table a_table (id int, data json);
insert into a_table values
(1, '{"bookIds": [1,2,3,5], "storeIds": [2,3]}'), 
(2, '{"bookIds": [4,5,6,7], "storeIds": [1,3]}'),
(3, '{"bookIds": [11,12,10,9], "storeIds": [4,3]}');
```

Note the proper syntax of json values.

You can use the function [`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)

```
select id, array_agg(book_id::text::int) as book_ids
from a_table
cross join json_array_elements(data->'bookIds') a(book_id)
group by 1
order by 1;

 id |   book_ids
----+--------------
  1 | {1,2,3,5}
  2 | {4,5,6,7}
  3 | {11,12,10,9}
(3 rows)
```

Use [`any()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-comparisons.html) to search for an element in the arrays, e.g.:

```
select *
from (
    select id, array_agg(book_id::text::int) as book_ids
    from a_table
    cross join json_array_elements(data->'bookIds') a(book_id)
    group by 1
    ) s
where 
    1 = any(book_ids) or
    11 = any(book_ids);

 id |   book_ids
----+--------------
  1 | {1,2,3,5}
  3 | {11,12,10,9}
(2 rows)
```

Read also about [`<@ operator`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html).

You can also search in json array (without converting it to int array) by examine its elements, e.g.:

```
select t.*
from a_table t
cross join json_array_elements(data->'bookIds') a(book_id)
where book_id::text::int in (1, 11);

 id |                     data                      
----+-----------------------------------------------
  1 | {"bookIds" : [1,2,3,5], "storeIds": [2,3]}
  3 | {"bookIds" : [11,12,10,9], "storeIds": [4,3]}
(2 rows)
```

### Generic functions

You might want to have generic tools for conversion from JSON arrays. Use the function to convert a JSON array of arbitrary strings:

```sql
create or replace function jsonb_text_array(jsonb)
returns text[] language sql immutable as $$
    select array(select jsonb_array_elements_text($1));
$$;
```

The resulting array is `text[]` that can be cast to `int[]`. However, when dealing specifically with integer arrays, this function should be significantly faster:

```sql
create or replace function jsonb_integer_array(jsonb)
returns integer[] language sql immutable as $$
    select translate($1::text, '[]', '{}')::integer[];
$$;

select id, jsonb_integer_array(data::jsonb->'bookIds') as book_ids
from a_table;

 id |   book_ids
----+--------------
  1 | {1,2,3,5}
  2 | {4,5,6,7}
  3 | {11,12,10,9}
(3 rows)
```

Note that JSONB has been available since Postgres 9.4.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my problem is how do i serach for elements than? suppose i want to search for rows containing 1 and 11.

Comment: This works like a charm but only problem when i search for more than one element of same row it gives duplicate. For example  

select t.*
from a_table t, json_array_elements(data->'bookIds') e
where e::text::int = any ('{1, 2}' :: int[]); it gives me row one two times. I can apply distinct .

Answer (score 9):

These two functions (for `json`/`jsonb`) modified from [a fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244285/316857) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45243186/316857) work perfectly

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_array_castint(json) RETURNS int[] AS $f$
    SELECT array_agg(x)::int[] || ARRAY[]::int[] FROM json_array_elements_text($1) t(x);
$f$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_castint(jsonb) RETURNS int[] AS $f$
    SELECT array_agg(x)::int[] || ARRAY[]::int[] FROM jsonb_array_elements_text($1) t(x);
$f$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

You can use them as follows:

```
SELECT json_array_castint('[1,2,3]')
```

Which gives the expected return `{1,2,3}` as in `integer[]`. If you wonder why I'm concatenating with an empty array in each of the `SELECT` statement it's because the cast is lossy and without it, if you try to cast an empty `json`/`jsonb` array to an `integer[]` you'll get no return (not desired) instead of an empty array (as expected). With the above method when you do

```
SELECT json_array_castint('[]')
```

You'll get `{}` instead of nothing. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48012658/316857) for more on why I added that.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had to cast json data stored in a table col to pg array  format and this was handy :

```
-- username is the table column, which has values like ["john","pete","kat"]

select id, ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements_text((username)::json)) usernames
from public.table-name;

-- this produces : {john,pete,kat}
```

Comment: This literally did exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would go a bit simpler:

```
select * from
(
select t.id, value::text::int as bookvalue
  from testjson t, json_array_elements(t.data->'bookIds')
) as t
where bookvalue in (1,11)
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e69aa/37

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest all in one line**

```
SELECT translate('[1,2,3,4]'::jsonb::text, '[]', '{}')::int[]
```

returns an integer array

```
{1,2,3,4}::int[]
```

and within a query...

```
SELECT translate(field->>'mykey', '[]', '{}')::int[]
```

nb! the double arrow `->>` where `field->>'mykey'` will return a ::text