# Postres: "No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, postgresql, casting

I'm trying to convert a JSON integer array to a postgres array for doing a WHERE clause, but I can't get it right. Tried casting to the array and to the whole subquery but I keep getting:

> "LINE 1: select id from story where id in (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT
> jsonb_... 
> No operator matches the given name and argument types.
> You might need to add explicit type casts."

my query:

```
SELECT id FROM story WHERE id IN (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements('[1000]'))::int[]);
```

Could please someone help? Thanks!

Comment: There are some details of `jsonb_array_elements` that you appear to have missed.  Read [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html).

Comment: In particular, a cast appears to be required here.  See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686187).

Comment: thanks both, I'm browsing the docs for about 2 hours now, tried casting to text than in like in @RobertHarvey's link, still getting the same error.

Comment: Try the contains operator:  `select id from story where '[1000]'::jsonb @> id::text::jsonb;`

Comment: `select '1000'::jsonb in (SELECT jsonb_array_elements('[1000]')); t`